# fprintf(textFilepointer) print twice into file

Tags: c, file, printf, do-while

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *textFilePointer;

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int note;

    printf("Press key on Axiom MIDI keyboard to display note number\n");


    textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/jonnymaguire/Documents/Uni Work/Audio Programming /iap/iapProj/Builds/MacOSX/build/Debug/textp15.txt", "w");

    do
    {
        if(textFilePointer == NULL)
        {
            printf("!Error Opening File!");
        }
        else
        {
            /*get frequency from user*/

            note = aserveGetNote();

            fprintf(textFilePointer, "note = %d\n", note);
            fprintf(textFilePointer, "hex note = %x\n\n", note);
            counter++;


        }

    }
    while(counter < 16);

    fclose(textFilePointer);

    return 0;               /*end*/
}
```

This program is simply to print the note numbers into a file once they have been played on the keyboard by the user. However it print double of everything, so instead of recording 15 different note numbers and hex note numbers I can only play in 8 as it writes double each time. why?

Comment: Side note: Put the `if(textFilePointer == NULL)` section **OUTSIDE** the `do/while` loop (a little tiny bit of basic logic if you don't mind).

Comment: The loop iterates 16 times and in each iteration it writes 3 text lines to the file: One with the note value, one with its hex value, and a blank line. What output are you expecting?

Comment: it writes the note value and hex value twice. "note = 67 hex note = 6c note = 67 hex note = 6c"

Comment: This means I can only press 8 notes before the program ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting **two** messages for every note played, one for a key press, one for a key release, you will be able to tell this by printing the note messages to a console, instead of to a file. Try this:

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) { 
    int counter = 0;
    int note;
    printf("Press key on Axiom MIDI keyboard to display note number\n");
    do
    {
        /*get frequency from user*/
        note = aserveGetNote();
        printf("note = %d\n", note);
        counter++;
    }
    while(counter < 16);
    return 0;
}
```